# Maximum value for jboss 7.1.1 ejb3 default-access-timeout

Tags: jboss, timeout, ejb, jboss7.x

What is the maximum allowed value for the jboss 7.1.1 ejb3 default-access-timeout shown in the xml snippet below?

I wasn't able to find it on google or here. Is there a way to set it to infinity?

Thanks.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to -1, see if that makes a difference.